# Is there a way to set up Apache Storm latest version under windows 10?

Tags: windows, apache-storm

I need to install Apache Storm as a single node cluster under Windows 10.
The latest instruction I found is:

http://ptgoetz.github.io/blog/2013/12/18/running-apache-storm-on-windows/

In the latest archive, Storm does not contain any .cmd files so it looks like WinOS is not supported at all.

Is there a way to install 2+ version of Apache Storm under Windows OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is supported, but you need to either use the Powershell script (`storm.ps1`), or just call the Storm Python script directly (`storm.py`).

Regarding how to install it, the instructions for Linux and Windows are the same (see [this](https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.1.0/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html)). The only major difference should be whether you use Windows or Linux style paths in the `storm.yaml` file, and what tool you use to run Storm under supervision (e.g. `systemd` or Windows services).